# How to concatenate cells in excel with different color contents?

Tags: html, excel, format, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate cells in Excel with different color contents in each one, but the lack of my knowledge does not give me a clue how to do it.

---

As I you can see in the next image, everything is manually done. But I want to do it with format or html formulas (if does exist).

[image]

The first block of seven rows `2-8`, the color contents of the input columns `A-D` are different but the concatenate column result `E` is plain text. If there's a way to do it, I want the same color contents of each input column format be in the concatenate column.

Or maybe, as you can se in the second block of the other seven rows `9-15`, I want to give the four input columns of plain text `A-D`, and then the concatenate column `E` be with different color for each column input.

---

### Note

I was thinking in other way to do it, like saving the input columns as CSV file and then with code add HTML tags to change the format, and then with reverse engineering, open de CSV file with excel, but the problem is I don't know how to translate the format of HTML to excel.

Comment: We cannot do this directly in Excel. However, we have some workaround.

Comment: You can do it quite easy with VBA: [How to concatenate cell columns and keep text color in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4622-excel-concatenate-keep-text-color.html)